# In Pentaho how to load dynamically multiple CSV formats data into DB and each file can have different Cols?

Tags: java, pentaho

I have to load multiple CSV files around 60 formats and each file may have different columns. We consolidated all columns and created as one table in DB. How to map and load the file contents into the table?. Please any one give a solution for this scenario ASAP

Ex: CSV1:
    Column_1, Column_2,Column_3
    1, 11, 111
    2, 22, 222

CSV2:
  column_1, column_3, column_4, column_5
  3, 333, 3333, 33333
  4, 444, 4444, 44444

### O/p of Table data in DB:

```
Column1 Column_2 Column_3 Column_4 Column_5

      1       11      111
      2       22      222                          
      3               333     3333    33333 
      4               444     4444    44444
```

---

Comment: Take a look at the `ETL Metadata Injection` step. [ETL Metadata Injection](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/ETL+Metadata+Injection)